# Remote Desktop listening IP

Tags: windows, rdp, remote, desktop

I have multiple Windows 2012 R2 servers. Each server is using just one NIC port that has around 15 IPs binded to it. I want to configure RDP to only listen on one IP, I've configured rules on windows firewall which stop any outside connections however I want it to if I opened RDP on the server and entered 127.0.0.1 it wouldn't connect because the RDP service is not listening on that IP.

Can someone provide me with the commands I need to enter in to powershell?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost, which means "this host". You can't connect to another machine via 127.0.0.1. This means that you can't connect to your server from another system by trying to connect to it via 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Can you give us some context about why you want this?  I doubt what you literally asked for is possible, but perhaps there is some alternative that can be suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can only set it to bind to an adapter, not an IP. You would have to use windows firewall to restrict to the right IP. If you really want it to bind to the IP then if the servers are virtualised, you could add a second bridged network adapter which just has the specific IP on and bind to that adapter instead.